# how handle error in NSPredicate

Tags: iphone

when i try to match regular expression for Data . sometime application crashes with error

here is error description

'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE (string Ertyu, pattern [a-Z], case 0, canon 0)'

here is my code

```
 - (BOOL)isValidateString:(NSString *)inString ForRE:(NSString *)inRE {
BOOL isValidate=NO;
NSPredicate *thePredicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", inRE]; 
isValidate= [thePredicate evaluateWithObject:inString];
return isValidate;
```

}

and in this method RE is getting from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-Z]` is an invalid range because `Z` is before `a` in Unicode. If you want to match all alphabets, make the server return `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: thanks kenny. kenny is there any solution or api to know about invalid RE before calling NSPredicate

Comment: @pawan: You could use [exception handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocExceptionHandling.html).